# How can I determine if an array contains some element?

Tags: julia

How can I tell if an array contains some element?

I have been manually checking with a loop:

```
for x in xs
    if x == a
        return true
    end
end
return false
```

Is there a more idiomatic way?

Answer (score 14):

The [`in`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/collections/#Base.in) operator will iterate over an array and check if some element exists:

```
julia> xs = [5, 9, 2, 3, 3, 8, 7]

julia> 8 in xs
true

julia> 1 in xs
false
```

It is important to remember that [`missing` values](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/missing/) can alter the behavior you might otherwise expect:

```
julia> 2 in [1, missing]
missing
```

`in` can be used on general [collections](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/collections/). In particular, matrices:

```
julia> A = [1 4 7
            2 5 8
            3 6 9]
3×3 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  4  7
 2  5  8
 3  6  9

julia> 7 in A
true

julia> 10 in A
false
```